Analog of Jensen Inequality
Jensen's inequality states that if $\phi$ is a convex function, then we have that:
$$
\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])\leq \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)] 
$$
Where in this case X is a discrete random variable.
Is there any bound to the other side? I mean,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)] \leq ?
$$
In particular, I've been trying to bound $E[-\log(X)]$. I also have the variance of $X$, let's just call the mean and the variance $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

First I think you mean $$\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)] \leq ?$$
Second, do you need an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$  only based on $\mathbb{E}(X)$?

My bad, edited the question with the updated information

When $\phi$ is twice differentiable, this paper shows that
$$\sigma^2\inf \frac{\phi''(x)}{2} \leq E\left[\phi \left(X\right)\right]-\phi\left(E[X]\right)\le \sigma^2\sup \frac{\phi''(x)}{2},$$
which yields the Jensen inequality if $\phi''(x)\ge 0$. Moreover, it gives the upper bound $$\phi\left(\mu\right) + \lambda \sigma^2  $$ for $E\left[\phi \left(X\right)\right]$ when $\lambda=\sup \frac{\phi''(x)}{2}$ is finite.
When $\phi''(x)$ is not finite over the support of $X$, $\lambda$ becomes infinite, and so does the upper bound, which is the case for $\phi(x)=-\log x$. However, if the support of $X$ is $(l, u)$ for some $l>0$, you can use the above bound with $\lambda=\frac{1}{2l^2}$.
You can also use the approximation given here for $E\left(\log X\right)$.
